# Find questions (words before "?") Regex Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, wildcards

I have several books that are improperly formatted that contain, among other things **QUESTIONS** and Answers.

My job is to make all the questions **CAPITALIZED AND BOLD.** I'm using MS Word to maintain the parts that are already correctly formatted, so moving it into Notepad++ (for example) and back isn't an option.

The only possible solution I can imagine working is using wildcards to find all words before "?" and none after, then replacing them with the formatting options already in MS Word's replace tool.

So, does anyone know how?

How do I find questions (words before "?") using Regex/wildcards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a macro that will do what you want. This macro assumes that your questions are in their own paragraph.  If they might be interspersed into a paragraph, you could use a while loop to keep expanding the selection character by character until you hit a capital letter, rather than just expanding to the whole paragraph.

> `Sub FormatQuestions() 
> 'Finds everything that starts with a capital letter and ends with a question mark. Bolds it and puts it in all caps. 
>
> 'Variable definitions
> Dim intTotalChars As Integer 
> Dim intLoop As Integer 
> Dim strTestChar As String 
> Dim rngQuestionRange As Range 
> Dim intCountQuestionMarks As Integer
>
> intTotalChars = ActiveDocument.Characters.Count
>
> For intLoop = 1 To intTotalChars     
>   strTestChar = ActiveDocument.Characters.Item(intLoop).Text
>
>   If strTestChar = "?" Then
>     intCountQuestionMarks = intCountQuestionMarks + 1
>     ActiveDocument.Characters.Item(intLoop).Select
>     Selection.Expand wdParagraph
>     Selection.Font.Bold = True
>     Selection.Font.AllCaps = True
>   End If
>
> Next intLoop
> End Sub`

In a previous version of this answer, I'd noted incorrectly that Word doesn't let you search for paragraph marks and wildcards at the same time.  Actually it does, but you need to use ^13 for a paragraph instead of ^p. (This page from Microsoft lists the special characters that can be used with a wildcard search: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176776)